# Dialog not playing exit animation when you return to app

Tags: java, android, animation, dialog

I create a dialog that is a pause menu when a player pauses the game/leaves the app and when you return and for example resume, it doesn't play the exit animation that it is supposed to, it only happens when you leave the app and return to it. Is there a way to fix it? Is it normal?

Because its not the animation fault, which is working perfectly fine when you pause/resume in app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went around it by dismissing the dialog on app exit and showing another one on return.